# Paypal payment processing with REST api

Tags: php, rest, api, paypal

I set up simple paypal check out with Rest Api (not credit card payment).

Everything works perfectly in Sandbox mode, but when I switch to Live mode and use Live mode clientID with Secret key. I get this error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'PayPal\Exception\PayPalConnectionException' with message 'Got Http response code 401 when accessing https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token.' in /vendor/paypal/rest-api-sdk-php/lib/PayPal/Core/PayPalHttpConnection.php:154
Stack trace:
#0 /vendor/paypal/rest-api-sdk-php/lib/PayPal/Auth/OAuthTokenCredential.php(241): PayPal\Core\PayPalHttpConnection->execute('grant_type=clie...')
#1 /vendor/paypal/rest-api-sdk-php/lib/PayPal/Auth/OAuthTokenCredential.php(266): PayPal\Auth\OAuthTokenCredential->getToken(Array, '***', '***...', 'grant_type=clie...')
#2 /vendor/paypal/rest-api-sdk-php/lib/PayPal/Auth/OAuthTokenCredential.php(210): PayPal\Auth\OAuthTokenCredential->generateAccessToken(Array, NULL)
#3 /vendor/paypal/rest-api-sdk-php/lib/PayPal/Auth/OAuthTokenCredential.php(160 in /vendor/paypal/rest-api-sdk-php/lib/PayPal/Core/PayPalHttpConnection.php on line 154
```

It happens only in Live mode... I checked all keys and everything is set up correctly, from my point of view. Please, let me know how this can be fixed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is solved!

I needed to add the folowing code to configure Live mode manually:

```
$paypal->setConfig(
      array(
        'mode' => 'live',
        'log.LogEnabled' => true,
        'log.FileName' => 'PayPal.log',
        'log.LogLevel' => 'FINE'
      )
    );
```

Comment: For laravel : $apiContext->setConfig need to be set.
https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK/wiki/Adding-Configurations